# Googlemaps not allowing me to locate the users location?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, gmsmapview

I am trying to create a view controller on swift that shows where the user is located. I have already implemented google maps, so now all I have to do is plug in the correct code. When doing so, I keep getting these two error messages then the app crashes. Can someone help me with figuring out a solution> any and all help is appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase
import MapKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class mainViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var mapView = GMSMapView()
    var camera = GMSCameraPosition()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyBDOLisA3c-wDTbkbSssAxEb3iLw7Y5vHo")

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, zoom: 17)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        view = mapView

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!)
        marker.snippet = "Current Location"
        marker.map = mapView
        self.mapView.addSubview(mapView)

        view.backgroundColor = GREEN_Theme
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.title = "Welcome"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Logout))
        }
    @objc func Logout() {
        print("Logged Out")
        do {

// I am receiving this error message on the auth.auth().signOut() "Use of unresolved identifier 'Auth'"
            try  Auth.auth().signOut()
            defaults.set(false, forKey: "user is logged in")
            let loginController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController())
            present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch let err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize, I am receiving the error here  (let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, zoom: 17)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        view = mapView) the message says Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) please help me fix this problem!

Comment: You have created an instance of GMSMapView by declaring the variable mapView, and then you declare again a constant of mapView?

Comment: @Do2 thank you, can you explain to me how to fix this?

Comment: @Do2 when I remove the let, I get a “use of unresolved identifier ‘mapView’

Comment: did you try self.mapView ?

Comment: I am getting the same error

Comment: "unable to create a map view that locates user current position"  You don't even have a line with the isMyLocationEnabled property for an GMSMapView object.

Comment: @Do2 your code worked perfectly! My app no longer crashes however I can no longer see the mapView, it’s just a plan black screen. Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: @ElTomato I tried to create that method, do you know where I should place it and how I should call it? I’m just getting a black screen

Comment: @ElTomato I think I may be plugging in your answers in the wrong area. I’m trying to make sure they’re put in their respective spots, however I keep getting hit with error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `CLLocationManager` does not have enough time to fetch the info and in the meantime other functions ask for that info which its still nil.

The below will take care the issue, it also stops updating the locations all the time which can be battery draining especially considering that you have set AccuracyBest.

```
func getLocation(){
    locationManager=CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    let lastLocation=locations[locations.count-1]
    if lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy>0{
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        let latitude = lastLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = lastLocation.coordinate.longitude

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyBDOLisA3c-wDTbkbSssAxEb3iLw7Y5vHo")
// everything that is going to require the latitude and longitude from the location manager goes here
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, zoom: 17)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        self.view = mapView

        let marker = GMSMarker()
         marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!)
         marker.snippet = "Current Location"
         marker.map = mapView
         self.mapView.addSubview(mapView)
      }
 }
```

Your `viewDidLoad` should have:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getLocation()

    view.backgroundColor = GREEN_Theme
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.title = "Welcome"
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Logout))
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much! My application no longer crashes however, I no longer have the mapView. It just the background color

Comment: Your question was how to fix your crash, i answered it. Now you are asking a new question, El Tomato answered it. You have posted a new question on this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Google Map as your map view, which means that you create an instance of the `GMSMapView` class.  That's an object.  You have one.  And I assume that it's IBOutlet-wired.  It comes with several delegate methods.  So you may want to set its delegate.  And you want your view controller to receive data from GMSMapView.  So you set the delegate of that class to self (your view controller).

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class mainViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {
    // MARK: - Instance variables
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    // MARK: - IBActions

    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    }
    // MARK: - Life cycle


    // MARK: - GMSMapView delegate methods
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        reverseGeocodeCoordinate(position.target) // sending data when the mapView is not moved or pinched by the finger //
    }

    func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response, error in
            guard let address = response?.firstResult(), let lines = address.lines else {
                return
            }

            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve this issue! I’m still running into problems because I don’t think I know where to correctly plug these in..

Comment: I am not using an interface builder. I am plugging in all of my codes programmatically